# Java Spring Framework: Component, Repository, Service - различия

Tags: java, spring

Поясните в чем разница между: `Component`, `Repository`, `Service` в **Java Spring Framework**.

Приведите простые примеры использования.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

`@Component` - это любой произвольный бин, который Spring сможет найти через `autoscan`.

Пример: вы реализовали какой-то класс и хотите сделать его экземпляр доступным через `@Autowired`.

---

Остальные аннотации обозначают слои  типичной многослойной архитектуры:

- `@Repository` - это `@Component` с семантикой DAO-слоя. То место, где вы ходите в базу данных. Spring завернет бросаемые классом исключения в `DataAccessException`.
- `@Service` - это `@Component` с семантикой слоя бизнес-логики.
- `@Controller` - это `@Component` с семантикой web-слоя. Такие бины Spring превратит в сервлеты.

Comment: Прошу добавить ссылки на источник

Comment: @Bato-BairTsyrenov  Это все так или иначе есть в официальной документации и JavaDoc.